# incompatible types: cell to String any idea how to resolve the problem?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read the content of an Excel's cell and insert it in an array list but I get the following error: incompatible types, cell cannot be converted to String
how to fix the problem plz?!!

a part of the code where the error exists:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    int j=0;
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        Double cellValue;
        cellValue = Double.parseDouble(cell);
        dataPoint.add(cellValue);
        System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
    }
```

Comment: Do [getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) as it is recommend in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Double#parseDouble` takes an `String` argument but you are trying to pass `Cell` object to it.

You can get the cell value using `cell.getStringCellValue();`. So, your code should looks like below :

```
cellValue = Double.parseDouble(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

If you face any issue to get cell value as String from a `numeric cell` you can set the cell type to `String` by calling `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)`  before getting the value from the cell.

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cellValue = Double.parseDouble(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

**Edit:**

However, it is recommended that we should check the cell type and then get the value of the cell accordingly instead of setting the cell type `Cell#setCellType` for getting the value. For more info please visit the [link](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).

Comment: i do it and I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell

Comment: It is not to recommend changing all cell types to string. If you are doing this with numeric cells which are referred in math formulas then those formulas probably will not work using string cell contents. Instead do [getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) as it is recommend.

Comment: @AxelRichter yes I agree with you. In general, we should check the cell type and then get the cell content accordingly.

Comment: I tried to check the content before but I get error in the row: CellType.NUMERIC.the error is incompatible types: cell types cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

the new code where I tried to check the cell's type first!!

```
  for (Row row : sheet1) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {


        // Alternatively, get the value and format it yourself
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case CellType.NUMERIC:
                cellValue=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;

            default:
                CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
                System.out.println("The cell"+cellRef.formatAsString()+"Does not contain numeric value");
        }
        dataPoint.add(cellValue);
        }
    }
```